# Change element text value using jquery not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have one form generated from rails. I tried to change to the input `order_bill` using Jquery in the firefox firebug console, but it does not work. I am new to `jQuery`.

```
<form class="edit_order" id="edit_order_1" action="/orders/1" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" />
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="1IBaRCZ4S1hYp1" />
    ..
    <div id="bill", class="field">
        <label for="order_应付款项">应付款项</label><br>
        <input type="text" value="4200" name="order[bill]" id="order_bill" />
    </div>
    <div class="actions"> .. </div> 
    <div class="actions">
    </div>
</form>
```

In the firebug JS console,

```
$('#order_bill').html("asdasdddddddddddddddd");
$('#order_bill').html("asdasdddddddddddddddd");
$('#order_bill').html("asdasdddddxx");
$('#bill').html("asdasdddddxx");
```

But none change on the Html page. Am I wrong?

Comment: To change the `value`, use `val()`. `html()` is used to change the `innerHTML` of an element.

Comment: use `.val()` for input

Comment: Well, just out of curiosity, why .html() won't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.prop() VS .val() .Setting an input text value with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093534/prop-vs-val-setting-an-input-text-value-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#order_bill').val("asdasdddddddddddddddd");
```

instead of `html();`

because the value you want to change is present in value attribute of  tag.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to make sure you import a jquery library in your html page
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js

if you want to get value just Type
$('#order_bill').value

and set the value
$('#order_bill').value = "enter Value"

But if You Want to add a text in div using jquery

$('#order_bill').html("Value");

Comment: `$('#order_bill').value = ...` won't work, that will create a `value` property on the jQuery object rather than on the actual DOM element.

Comment: Please tell me why you use jquery for this so i will guide you properly.